# Flask-Admin Mongoengine modifying model view

Tags: flask, mongoengine, flask-admin

Using Flask-Admin with Mongoengine, I am stuck when trying to customize model view for the list of submitted posts.
The idea is to add a cell to each post (corresponding to a row in the list) in order to show the number of comments submitted on each post.

I have added the following `get` method to the class:

```
class PostView(ModelView):

   def get(self):
       posts = Post.objects.all()
       return render_template('admin/model/list.html', posts=posts)
```

The list.html contains the following:

```
<td>
    {% for d in posts %}
        {% with total=d.comments | length %}
            {{ total }}
        {% endwith %}
    {% endfor %}
<td>
```

The table cells stay empty. What should I do instead ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand you trying create own view but I can't find any `get` method in `ModelView`.

Anyway `flask-admin` have flexible inheritance structure. So you can try just:

```
class PostView(ModelView):
    list_template = 'admin/model/posts-list.html'
```

**templates/admin/model/posts-list.html**:

```
{% extends 'admin/model/list.html' %}

{% block list_header %}
    {{ super() }}
    <th>Comments count</th>
{% endblock %}

{% block list_row %}
    {{ super() }}
    <td>{{ row.comments|length }}</td>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works indeed ... would you please explain `{{ row.comments|length }}`, how does this effectively relate to the Monngodb collection ? And maybe suggest any docs about the topic (creation of own views after querying the database...) Regards

Comment: In this case `row` just `Post` instance see: https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/templates/admin/model/list.html#L93, https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/model/base.py#L942 and https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/contrib/mongoengine/view.py#L254. To create own view see again to `list.html`, https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-admin/tree/master/examples/layout and http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templates/.